# How to add :hover affects to fa-fa icons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, font-awesome

I couldn't find out how to add the pseudo :hover to the "Font-awesome" icons (fa-fa icons).

If somebody could help i would be greatly appreciative.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="overview"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" style="margin-top:10px;"></i></a><br />
<a href="#" class="tier"><i class="fa fa-level-up fa-2x" style="margin-top:10px;"></i></a>
```

CSS:

```
.overview, .tier {
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: That works for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/Lgvbbqeo/

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works, but it'll also color any text that  contains. If you want to apply the color only when you hover the icon, put it on the class fa like you did with the a tag.

```
.fa:hover { 
    color: red
}
```

or if you want to specify it per icon:

```
.fa-level-up:hover {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: add `:hover` to `fa-level-up` :)

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm an idiot. I had a z-index in some other code stopping it from working! Thanks alot! I needed that help too!